# Queue modulus in en-queue and de-queue method?

Tags: java, queue

So I have this code I need to analyze and learn from it, about how bounded queue works, here it is:

```
class Queue<T> { // bounded

    private T[] seq; // the sequence
    private int size = 0; // size of sequence
    private int head = 0; private int tail = 0; // front and rear

    Queue(int n) { // n>0
        seq = (T[])(new Object[n]); 
    }

    Queue(){ this(10000);} // =  seq=(T[])(new Object[10000]);

    boolean isEmpty() { return size==0;}

    boolean enq(T t) { 
        if (size<seq.length) {
                seq[tail] = t; tail = (tail+1)%seq.length; size++; 
                return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    T deq() {
        if (isEmpty()) return null;
        else {
            T temp = seq[head];
            head = (head+1)%seq.length; size--;
            return temp;
        }
    }
}
```

So everything is okay, but I don't understand why in the name of god is there a modulus (`%`) operation in the `enq(T t)` method and `deq()` method...

Comment: Well what would happen if you removed it?

Comment: The next element of the array would be the new tail...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a modulus operation so that the queue can be represented by an array, where the contents of the queue "wrap around" the end of the array to the beginning.

Example with a size of 10:

```
[6th] [tail] [empty] [empty] [empty] [head] [2nd] [3rd] [4th] [5th]
```

Here, head = 5, and tail = 1, because a total of 12 items have been added and 5 removed.  Even if there isn't enough room at the end of the array, there is room at the beginning of the array to store more data up until the capacity of the array.

The modulus operations allow the `head` and `tail` to wrap around on a `deq` and `enq` operation, respectively, so that `9` becomes `0` instead of `10`, which would have caused an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I just thought about it a second before you wrote this answer! :D
Thank you for approving my thought ^^

Comment: But now that I think of it... Let's say I have an array of 10 elements and the queue takes up the element 2-3-4-5-6 so the elements 0-1 and 7-8-9 are empty.. If I add to the queue the tail is 7 so element no. 7 gets the data and then tail becomes `(tail+1)%array.length` which will give 8%10=2.. so how suddenly tail becomes the head?

Comment: No, `8 % 10` is `8`.  The modulus won't "reset" it to 0 until it reaches 10.  `9 % 10` is `9`, but `10 % 10` is `0`.

Comment: Ohhh! Yeah I mistakened it with mod 2.. sorry :P it's 1:10 am and I'm up from 8:50 am studying for tomorrow and still have 4 lectures to go over :( Thank you very much!!!